# Adding clicked element html from prev page to another element on next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to insert the html that was clicked on a previous page into another element on the next page?

Clicking this said element will direct to the next page. I want to be able to carry 'this' clicked element and associated data bits over to next page.

```
$tags.on('click', 'a', function(){
        var clickedTag = $(this).text();
        // persist this value into next page
        $('.tag .intro h1').text(clickedTag);
    })
```

Comment: To send the information as part of the URL (query string) is an option? Or use a cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries)

```
//1 page click (set)
history.pushState({clickedText: 'text'}, 'Title');
//2 page click (get)
history.state.clickedText
```